# If $\mid a_{jj}\mid \gt \sum_{i \neq j} \mid a_{ij} \mid$ then vectors $a_1,\dots ,a_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly indendent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1,\dots ,a_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $a_i = (a_{i1}, \dots , a_{in})$.

Show that when $\mid a_{jj}\mid \gt \sum_{i \neq j} \mid a_{ij} \mid \; \forall \; j\in \{1,\dots ,n\}$, then $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ are linearly independent.

I want to show that the matrix \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{n1} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{n2} \\ \vdots & & \ddots & \\ a_{1n} & a_{2n} & \cdots & a_{nn} \end{matrix} can be transformed into an upper triangular matrix with all entries in the main diagonal $\neq 0$.

For the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ this is easy. However, I fail to show this for the general case; the problem being that the tranformations mess up the coefficients such that I can't use the assumption on the $a_{jj}$'s anymore.

I'm pretty sure that this has already been solved somewhere on here, but I don't know how to search for it.

Comment: See Hadamard's lemma

Comment: See [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), the eigenvalues of the matrix is located inside the union of closed discs $\cup_{j=1}^n \bar{B}\left(a_{jj},\sum_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}|\right)$ which doesn't contain the origin. So the matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Suppose $v^T=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ is a row vector such that $v^TA=0$. Let $v_k$ be the largest-sized element among all elements of $v$. By considering the $k$-th element of $v^TA$, show that $v^T=0$.